# Removing My Sites menu from Admin

Tags: multisite, customization

I am trying to find a solution to remove the "My Sites" menu that comes under the Dashboard section of a multi-site install. Any ideas on which hook to use?

[image]

Comment: You'll have to intercept the global for the wp admin menu. Give it a try and file an [edit] with how far you got.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `remove_submenu_page` to remove it. Note that it doesn't prevent visiting that page if you manually enter the URL.

```
function adjust_the_wp_menu() {
    $page = remove_submenu_page( 'index.php', 'my-sites.php' );
}
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'adjust_the_wp_menu', 999 );
```

Based on the example from [`remove_submenu_page` Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/remove_submenu_page).